# Ionic 2 - IMG tag web source, where are images stored?

Tags: html, image, angular, ionic-framework, android-image

Using Ionic for the first time, I have a loop where I set a number of img tags to a random source - the source of the img is on the web e.g:

```
<img [src]="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/1200px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png" />
```

When the app runs, i assume the img is downloaded somewhere locally to display (cached?)? My assumption may be wrong here.

If it is - where is it saved? the reason I ask is that if I want to then share the image (native mobile share sheet) I want to share the local copy not download the img again (especially expensive for gifs).

I'm hoping not to need to handle saving the images locally manually.

Thank you,

Comment: it's the browser's job to cache images from appropriate server headers, you cannot do it from front-end i.e angular

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, so to confirm - i cannot access this browser cache - find the path of the cached img?

Comment: you can use any number of ionic 2 image caching libraries to specifically cache the image you need